# John and Lowner ellipsoid

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, convex-optimization

I am looking at a proof to show that Lowner ellipsoids are unique for centrally symmetric convex body $K$. I want to show basically that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\Vol}{Vol}\DeclareMathOperator{\Low}{Low}\DeclareMathOperator{\John}{John}
\Low(K)=\John(K^{\circ})^{\circ},
$$
where the $\circ$ means polar sets. To do so, I want to show that the minimization problem to find the Lowner ellipsoid is the same as the maximization problem to find the John ellipsoid on the polar convex body $K^{\circ}$. The proof says that it is trivial since $$
\Vol\big(\Low(K)\big)\cdot \Vol\big(\Low(K)^{\circ}\big)$$ equals the volume of the unit ball squared, and that
$$
K \subset \Low(K) \iff \Low(K)^\circ \subset K.
$$
I don't know how to connect the pieces together, however.